# Ghostscript pdf to pdf/a-3 conversion results in a colorspace validation error by VeraPDF

Tags: ghostscript, file-conversion, pdfa

I'm converting a pdf 1.5 file via. the latest Ghostscript cli to pdf/a-3 format, but by validating the output file with VeraPDF, I get an error.

I used the command:

```
gswin64 -dPDFA=3 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sColorConversionStrategy=UseDeviceIndependentColor -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf
```

- but by validating the output file with VeraPDF, I get the following colorspace error:

"DeviceRGB shall only be used if a device independent DefaultRGB colour space has been set when the DeviceRGB colour space is used, or if the file has a PDF/A OutputIntent that contains an RGB destination profile."

[VeraPDF validation error 6.2.4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WIbY.png)

What could be wrong here (with the commands?)?

Comment: You should report a bug, don't forget to include the exact version and the input file. Though basically the simple answer would be not to use DeviceIndependentColor, use a device colour space and ICC profile. You have not used a pdfa_def.ps file, which means that you won't get an OutputICCProfile in your PDF file so any device colour spaces simply won't be valid.

Comment: @KenS Thanks for your reply!

I tried this `gswin64 -dPDFA=3 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sOutputFile=output_filename.pdf -sOutputICCProfile="C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.02.1\iccprofiles\srgb.icc" -dOverrideICC=true PDFA_def.ps input.pdf`

but this results in an additional validation error about the gray color space:
"DeviceGray shall only be used if a device independent DefaultGray colour space has been set when the DeviceGray colour space is used, or if a PDF/A OutputIntent is present."
In PDFA_def.ps I set the path to srgb

Comment: As I mentioned in the bug report, you can't use a sRGB ICC profile as a RGB profile, beyond that I'll look at it when I have some free time. D'oh! I should read more carefully.. it's a busy morning. You can't use OutputICCProfile when doing colour conversion, it will turn all the output into sRGB which won't work. You haven't specified what's in pdfa_def.ps, and you **must** configure that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade to Ghostscript 10.3.0 and use of this command:

```
-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o good.pdf -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -dCompressPages=false -dWriteObjStms=false -dWriteXRefStm=false -dPDFA=3 --permit-file-read=/ghostpdl/iccprofiles/default_rgb.icc pdfa_def.ps input.pdf
```

with an icc-profile defined in pdfa_def.ps as:

```
% Define an ICC profile :
/ICCProfile (/ghostpdl/iccprofiles/default_rgb.icc) % Customise
def
```

as described here:

https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707450